# script to search all numeric no's greater than or equal to 13 digit

Tags: scripts

I have a requirement where i need to find the credit card no's in a set of files(*.txt, *.csv or any extension). Credit card no's are numeric and has a  minimum 13 numeric digits or more. So basically all the values which has 13 numeric digits or more.

I need to print all those credit card no's. Could you please help me?

Comment: Most of the time, credit card numbers include spaces, should the answer take care of that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use `grep`:

```
grep -Po '[0-9]{13}[0-9]*' numbers.txt
```

#### Example:

File contents:

```
Jack D     1234567890123
Ollie M    1234567890
Richard P  12345678901234567890
```

Output:

```
1234567890123
12345678901234567890
```

Comment: But it seems this command is not working properly. C:\Users\5001135\Desktop>grep -Po [0-9]{13}[0-9]* test.txt
test.txt:sunny1 1276547872136786212321
test.txt:sunny3 136767213798721387

C:\Users\5001135\Desktop>cat test.txt
sunny 12345678765456
sunny1 1276547872136786212321
sunny2 123567
sunny3 136767213798721387
sunny4 1234567891234

Comment: That would be because you are using Windows 7 not Ubuntu? And what is the error?

Comment: let me check on my server and i'll get back to you in a while. Thanks once again

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Thanks i have verified it on Linux server and its working fine, just one more requirement i need to print the whole line which matches this criteria and it should search the matching criteria in sub directories as well.

Comment: remove the letter `o` and you have to run it with each file.

Comment: @SunnySinghal If this works please click the tick below the down arrow!